# Communication between Spring to Android application using FCM

Tags: android, spring-boot, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is my Spring code that is responsible to generate a Firebase Cloud Messaging:

```
@Component
class FirebaseMessage {
    fun sendDataMessageToAndroidApp(msg: String) {
        val serverKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        val message: Message = Message.builder()
            .putData("verification", msg)
            .setTopic("/topics/QrCodeSample")
            .build()
        try {
            val response: BatchResponse = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAll(listOf(message))

            // Iterar pelas respostas para cada destino de mensagem
            for (sendResponse: SendResponse in response.responses) {
                if (sendResponse.isSuccessful) {
                    println("Mensagem enviada com sucesso para: ${sendResponse.messageId}")
                } else {
                    val exception: FirebaseMessagingException = sendResponse.exception
                    println("Falha ao enviar mensagem para: ${exception.errorCode}")
                    // Tratar a exceção ou erro aqui
                }
            }

        } catch (e: FirebaseMessagingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

And here my Android listener to the firebase messages:

```
class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        val SERIAL_NUMBER = "101"
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMessaging", "Mensagem recebida!")
        val messageBody = remoteMessage.notification?.body
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMessaging", messageBody!!)

        remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {
            if (it && remoteMessage.data["verification"] == SERIAL_NUMBER) {
                // Execute a função X em segundo plano
                Log.d("MyFirebaseMessaging", remoteMessage.data["verfication"]!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I´m trying to do is a communication, and not a notification push, from the Spring to the Android. The idea is just to send an ID anything that the user can handle, only to the application logic.

I´m really new to this technology and still beginner in this topic. All the Spring code run, but I do not know how to make sure that the message goes to the Cloud. And until now the message never arrive to the Android application, not even a log text by this class, seems to never run. I would like some help to know what is happening in this communication and chase were the massages is lost. Please I really need help to solve this.